# how to find descendents using a saved jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am looping through some unordered lists and I'd like to get all of the descendants by using only the saved selectors (both of which are wrapped with jquery objects).

Here is my sample HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 5</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">item 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 10</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">item 11</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 12</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 13</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 14</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 15</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">item 16</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 17</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 18</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 19</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 20</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is my sample JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    allUls   = $('ul');
    allAs    = allUls.find('a');

    // shouldn't this next line get all anchors within the second unordered list?
    console.log( allUls.eq(1).find(allAs) );

});
```

So there it is. I was expecting for an array of anchors that are descendants of the second list to be sent to the console. But that's not the case.

You can see for yourself on my jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/u6uf4/

I'm also open to any "better" solutions you may have. Just keep in mind, I'd like to use only the saved selectors and would like to avoid creating any new selectors for this task.

Thank you for your time and effort for helping a fellow Jquery-er!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The option to pass a jQuery object to `find()` was only recently added in **version 1.6**. Your jsfiddle example uses version 1.5.2. Select the latest jQuery version on the left to make it work.

Comment: lol. I applaud you for restraining yourself from using words like "retard" and "idiot" in your answer. Because I definitely feel like one. Thanks for stating the obvious. :)

Comment: Don't worry, we all know the feeling. This is how we know when it's time to go outside and have a pint :).

Answer (score 1):

Close, but you don't need to filter by allAs, just filter by 'a'.

```
allUls.eq(1).find('a')
```

Comment: But aren't you supposed to be able to just pass a jquery object as well? http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: I'd rather not have to traverse the dom again, ya know?

Comment: Yeah, but you would use filter and not find, but what you are doing is simple and easy enough to do with .find('a'). I edited my answer with both options

Comment: Wouldn't .filter('a') be checking if any 'ul's matched 'a'? For example: I would find every other UL like this: `allUls.filter(':even');` or I could find the second unordered list like this: `allUls.filter(':eq(1)');`. I could be wrong. Also, My example was just a simplified example. My actual code is more complex and needs to be optimized to the fullest extent. Thank you for your patience with a noobie. :)

Comment: yep, with filter I can only find this: allAs.filter(allUls.eq(1).find('a')).text("color2"); which is useless...

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I feel silly... according to the docs looks like you will need jQuery 1.6 to pass an object to "find", or traverse the dom each time you want to find the anchors in a specific ul.

Comment: That's ok. That means I'm not the only one who feels silly. Thanks anyways.